# Excel VBA Worksheetfunction.Match doesn't work with Dates

Tags: excel, vba

I need to apply `MATCH` function to a range of dates (**in VBA**. The standard `MATCH` function written as cell formula does work as intended.) looking for the largest possible index whose corresponding date is `<=` the looked-up date. Here's my code and a minimum working example:

```
Function test_debug_func(x As Date, arr As Range) As Integer
Debug.Print "entered function"
test_debug_func = WorksheetFunction.Match(x, arr, 1)

End Function
```

[image]

And I checked that the function is indeed entered by printing the debug statement. However, it cannot proceed with the `WorksheetFunction.Match` function. I also checked that all dates are indeed `Date` and not other formats.

It simply doesn't make any sense to me why this wouldn't work. Could anyone kindly help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since dates are just numbers, you can use `CLng`:

```vb
test_debug_func = WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(x), arr, 1)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks it works! But it's strange that I also tried `Cint` and it didn't work. Also, I would expect Excel to be smart enough to implicitly convert `Date` to `Integer` when comparing them, but it didn't...

Comment: The maximum value of an `Integer` is `32767`... your dates correspond to larger numbers, e.g. `2020/1/1` is `43831`, so you need `CLng` instead of `CInt`.